# Left justify a column using textplot (gplots or PerformanceAnalytics)

Tags: r

I'm writing some text in a data.frame to a PDF device using textplot() in gplots (also tried using the version in PerformanceAnalytics).  My par() options are the default ones, except I change the font/margins (CM is a family I defined in my site profile)

```
par( family = "CM" , omi = rep( .5 , 4 ) )
```

I'm trying to get the "Plot" column to be left justified.  Here is my failed attempt...notice the overlap in text

```
textplot( tableOfContents , show.rownames = FALSE , show.colnames = TRUE , hadj = 0 )
```

[image]

Right justified works just fine:

```
textplot( tableOfContents , show.rownames = FALSE , show.colnames = TRUE , hadj = 1 )
```

[image]

**EDIT**
If anyone else is struggling with alignment in texplot, I suggest a look at this modified version that I wrote:
https://gist.github.com/1487363

**EDIT2**
You might want to remove my cex=1 fix.  After some more reading I understand that cex in function parameters are supposed to be applied to par(cex), which I think is confusing and over-engineering but seems to be an R standard practice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the source code, I think the best way is with a slight modification so that the x position adapts to `hadj`, instead of staying constant. It might be worthwhile to suggest this change to the developer too. Here is a gist where you can download the modified version:

https://gist.github.com/1482973

Then just source it in R with `source()`, and you should be able to use the function like normal.

```
source('textplot.R')
n = 10
data = data.frame(Section=1:n, Plot=replicate(n, paste(LETTERS[sample(26, sample(20), replace=T)], collapse='')), Page=sort(rep(1:4, len=n)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

textplot(data, show.rownames = FALSE, show.colnames = TRUE, hadj=0)
```

[image]

Comment: sick!  thanks so much for the effort on this one.  I'll start a bounty on this when the wait-period expires so you can get awarded more points.  Also, will suggest this update to the developer

Comment: BTW, I made a number of modifications to textplot and produced a version that I think its a lot easier to use.  Posted here: https://gist.github.com/1487363   Modifications are detailed in header documentaiton.  Will update post with this link so others benefit from the work

Comment: @SFun28 I appreciate your comprehensive updates. It's great for when other people want to follow. If you don't mind, could you post back when you here back from the developer? Thanks!

Comment: Xu - absolutely!  Brian (author/maintainer) got back to me really quickly and said he would review the code and likely include it in the next version of PerformanceAnalytics.  Note Edit2 that I'm about to add to my original post.  Realized that I didn't follow R convention in one area